# Filter tasks on agenda file

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have specified two source Org files for Org-mode to search when creating an agenda. In the agenda view, how do I filter (view) tasks from only one of the files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After opening the agenda (`C-c a`), press `<` to add restrictions.  `<` once will restrict the agenda to the current buffer; `<` twice will restrict it the subtree the cursor is on.  `>` will remove the restrictions.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't do anything, so I posted the question. Any ideas? Also, how does that show me only agenda items in File1.org rather than the default, which shows agenda items from File1.org and File2.org.

Comment: `C-c a <` while the point is in File1.org should generate an agenda containing only items in File1.org